# jQuery radio buttons disappear after click in IE and FF, works fine in chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have multiple sets of jQuery radio buttons on a jQuery modal dialog.  Clicking one in each set hides or shows divs.  Anyway, they work perfectly in Chrome, but in FF and IE, they work hide/show the divs properly... but they start disappearing as they're clicked.

I've tried adding plain radio buttons that do nothing, but they still disappear individually as they're clicked.  Am I missing some sort of declaration?

I would post the code, but it can literally be a copy from the jQuery website for radio buttons and they'll still disappear.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle of your code or at least post some code, expecially your events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure what the problem is, but I implemented a work around.

In Chrome, I remember I had to add an unused jQuery radio button at the top... that hides when the dialog is opened... and "unhides" when the dialog is closed (the dialog is hidden when closed, so the user doesn't ever see this radio button).

For some reason I had to add another one of these jQuery radio buttons that hides and unhides itself to prevent the disappearing jQuery radio buttons in IE9 and FF. So in my case, Chrome required one of these fake buttons... while IE and FF needed two.

Anyway, I think the root of the problem stems from my overall layout template. I think multiple divs all over the place are screwing something up somewhere.

I'm just an amateur programmer so I know this isn't the solution that I'm sure many people would be looking for, but it works for now so at least I'm able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the same example page from another system? If all examples you can find have this behavior, I'd start to suspect your display driver or even hardware. Give a link for a page that you see the problem with, and we can see if it happens for us.